# Where is dragThatCannotResizeWindow in Interface Builder/Storyboard?

Tags: macos, autolayout, interface-builder

I found the [`NSLayoutConstraint.Priority.dragThatCannotResizeWindow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nslayoutconstraint/priority/1526902-dragthatcannotresizewindow) to be very useful. Though I usually write constraints with code, it sometimes gets too long and I want to move them to IB.

How I can set the priority of a constraint to be `dragThatCannotResizeWindow` in Interface Builder? There are only 3 options, corresponding to `required`, `defaultHigh`, `defaultLow` in code.

[image]

I tried looking up `dragThatCannotResizeWindow storyboard` on Google, and nothing useful came up (< 50 results!)

There are also a bunch of other priorities like `dragThatCanResizeWindow`, and `fittingSizeCompression`, which I'm also interested about.

One guess I had was that unlike `required`, `defaultHigh`, `defaultLow`, these "semantic" priorities don't have a fixed value, and hence cannot be selected in the storyboard.<sup>*</sup> Is this true? If so, what does their values depend on?

*<sub>This is kind of a weak reason since semantic colors like "label" and "background" don't have a fixed value either and *they* are in IB...</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Priority` is a struct with these "semantic" defined values:

```
.required:                       1000.0
.defaultHigh:                     750.0
.dragThatCanResizeWindow:         510.0
.windowSizeStayPut:               500.0
.dragThatCannotResizeWindow:      490.0
.defaultLow:                      250.0
.fittingSizeCompression:           50.0
```

As we know, Storyboard / IB lists only Required, High and Low ... but we can type any value between 0 and 1000 into the Priority field.